# Windows 7 Text to Speech Add More voices

Tags: php, windows-7, text-to-speech, sapi

I Create code for the text to speech application
I want to add more voice in the that application how to do it ??
I am using windows 7.
and Xampp.
I have only one anna defalt voice

```
<?php
$TTS = new COM("SAPI.SpVoice"); 
$TTS->Speak('Hello world!');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install any SAPI-compatible voice engine. Search it in internet, there are many variants. It appears on "control panel" in submenu "speech". You should choose the different default voice or manually enter voice name using TTS function SelectVoice(string voicename).